# Im getting a message that i use components but i dont use them any more

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Im getting this message everytime i open a solution on Visual Studio
[image]

which links to this [url](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/component-nuget/#Components_without_a_NuGet_migration_path)

But i don't have components any more (i don't have a components section under referenses and i dont have any components folder on solution path) and my project builds correctly. So how i can disable this message?

Comment: Most likely, the issue here is something in your .sln or .csproj file. At a guess (from the supplied url) it's something in the csproj file.

Comment: yeap, that was the problem, you can add your comment as solution to mark it :)